# Telethon issue, need to read messages from channels

Tags: python, warnings, bots, telegram

I've read a lot of answers here and tried their code, but I cannot get the examples to work for me and I don't understand why.

I want to capture messages from telegram channels but noone of telehon methods works for me...

I'm using telethon but it is not important how. I just need to capture these messages.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events,utils
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetFullChatRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetChannelsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel , sync
import re


client = TelegramClient('session_name', api id, api hash )
client.start()
my_self=client.get_me()
print(myself)
```

This is the output I get:

```
 C:/Users/Riccardo/Desktop/yobitpumpR.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 
 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited

 C:/Users/Riccardo/Desktop/yobitpumpR.py:19: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 
 'get_me' was never awaited
 <coroutine object get_me at 0x00000083F93E9410>
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: How this is connected to java? Please, remove misleading tag.

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: @Richard - found a solution? Went through the solutions here and on other platforms to store the data. None work.

Answer (score -1):

https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html This is very helpful it goes through from start to finish